# How do I use JavaScript decorators on a class instance via Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, decorator

Given the following `.babelrc` config:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {
      "legacy": false,
      "decoratorsBeforeExport": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

I can't get the class decorators to work:

```
@annotation
class MyClass { }

function annotation(target) {
   target.annotated = true;
}

const c = new MyClass();
console.log(c);
```

Also, `console.log(target)` yields the following:

`Object [Descriptor] { kind: 'class', elements: [] }`

For the `console.log(c)` statement I'd expect to see the annotated property added, however what I get is just `MyClass {}`.

Some additional clarification - I know of the `legacy: true` flag but I wish to use the spec as it is now, without the legacy fallback. I did some additional research and I think I'm on the right path here, here's the updated code:

```
@annotation
class MyClass { }

function annotation(descriptor) {
  const {
    kind,
    elements
  } = descriptor;

  const newElements = elements.concat([{
    kind: 'field',
    placement: 'own',
    descriptor: {
      annotated: true
    }
  }]);
  return {
    kind,
    elements: newElements
  }
}

const c = new MyClass();
console.log(c);
```

The above still doesn't work but at least I am no longer getting weird errors :)

*Please read the comments on the accepted answer to see some potential solutions to this, if interested.*

** UPDATE **
I actually managed to figure it out - using the `legacy: false` option:

```
@annotation
class MyClass { }

function annotation(descriptor) {
  const {
    kind,
    elements
  } = descriptor;

  const newElements = elements.concat([{
    kind: 'field',
    placement: 'own',
    key: 'annotated',
    initializer: () => true,
    descriptor: {
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true
    }
  }]);
  return {
    kind,
    elements: newElements
  }
}

const c = new MyClass();
console.log(c); // MyClass { annotated: true }
```

Comment: Thank you for this man, when using this non-legacy decorators, is there a way to add the `annotated` prop set to `true` to the `MyClass` constructor class itself like you would do with legacy decorators (i.e. without creating an instance of `MyClass`)? E.g.: `console.log(MyClass.annotated); // true`? Also, do is there a way to discriminate whether the decorator is being used with the legacy and non-legacy API? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find the specification or a tutorial explaining you how to use the `descriptor.elements` property when `"legacy": false, "decoratorsBeforeExport": false` ? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix, frankly, I can't remember. It's likely that it was a GH issue/discussion of some sort but I can't give you an exact link I'm afraid, sorry about that.

Comment: Found this article of yours: https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/using-decorators-in-javascript/ Gonna check it out tomorrow! Thank you anyway!

Comment: oh, and there's that ... (facepalm) haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a new class that sets the property in the constructor.

```js
@annotation
class MyClass { }

function annotation(target) {
  return class extends target {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      this.annotated = true;
    }
  }
}

const c = new MyClass();
console.log(c);
```

Comment: the above returns 'Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null'.

Comment: @Tamas Hmm...may have something to do with not using the legacy decorators. The newer proposal has a ton of intricacies.

Comment: @Tamas FWIW the people championing the proposal recommend using the legacy for now, if you aren't set in stone. `The decorators champion group would recommend continuing to use Babel "legacy" decorators or TypeScript "experimental" decorators.` [link](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#how-should-i-use-decorators-in-transpilers-today)

Comment: yes, I agree with you on the intricacies bit ... I think I'm close to a solution but it still doesn't work. I'll update my original question with some more info

Comment: I'm only experimenting so it's not a big deal but I really wanted to figure out how to use the new spec, with `legacy: false`

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I presume you realize that the _actual_ proposal uses a completely different syntax that has yet to be implemented.

Comment: I think my update to the original post reflects that new(ish) syntax? At least I thought that's the latest, but correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Take a look at the link I previously provided — there's an example of the syntax that isn't implemented. I presume that's why the champions recommend the legacy. I'm taking a look at the code produced by Babel now.

Comment: Another relevant [link](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10234#issuecomment-512566384) from only 6 days ago — from a Babel member: `The current proposal is not supported yet; I'm working on it.`

Comment: Alright, I suppose I'll park this project for now and get back to it whenever there's an update! Thanks

Comment: Sounds good. Hopefully Babel support will land at some point in the near future, though I wouldn't hold my breath. In the meantime, my answer at least provides you a way to use the legacy decorators.